# No wired or wireless networking available on Ubuntu 12.04 (wired work from LiveUSB)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, wired

I've just installed 12.04 in a dual boot with Vista via a LiveUSB. When I booted to the LiveUSB wired networking worked out of the box, and wireless networking didn't work. Now that I've installed 12.04 on a partition on the harddrive I can't get wired or wireless networking to work.

Any suggestions as how to how I should go about fixing this? The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=64
       resources: memory:fe5fe000-fe5fffff
```

Comment: That's very unfortunate to have both wireless and wired networking not working. Do you have an updated 12.04.2 (note the **.2**!) image? Did you also try 13.04?

Comment: It is indeed, and it seems strange that the wired networking worked  on the LiveUSB but not with the full install! Yes, I do have 12.04.2. I'd rather stick with that if possible, as it's the LTS. Is there now way I can download a driver and copy it accross on a flash drive?

Comment: Listen to @chili555 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional Drivers sometimes offers to install the wrong drivers! Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe b44
```

Now your ethernet should be working. Hook it up and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Upon reboot, both should be working fine.

Comment: After a couple of attempts that worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem but my wired connection is working and wireless is not working. I tried the above commands, restarted the system but wifi still does not work.

Comment: @Sachin I suggest you start your own new question and provide the wireless card details from: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Thanks for the response @chili555 but I had fixed the issue