# Cant use wired or wireless after ubuntu 13.10 installation

Tags: wireless

I installed Windows 8 on my hp laptop that time I faced no difficulty to connect using wired or wireless connection and everything happened automatically. Now I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I can't connect to same modem using either of internet connections..my Wi-Fi touch switch is not working. I checked BIOS but can't find anything to switch Wi-Fi setup of laptop on. I tried `rfkill` command it showed result as:

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Check if you have a button that blocks the wifi...

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Ubuntu and had the same problem. Here's a way 
restart your computer
when the choosing operating system screen appears, click on "Advanced Ubuntu users"..
 there will be a option of "recovery mode".. choose it
 then a screen will appear with couple of options, choose "repair dpkg files" and run it.. 
then go on "resume normal boot"..
and check if its done..

Comment: No..i still cant connect to internet

Answer (score 0):

Try these if they work...
[No wired or wireless networking available on Ubuntu 12.04 (wired work from LiveUSB)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324898/no-wired-or-wireless-networking-available-on-ubuntu-12-04-wired-work-from-liveu)

or

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082305&p=12350385#post12350385